# how to set layout two module side by side on same leftpanel in dnn

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

how to set layout two module side by side on same leftpanel in dnn

example :

```
<div runat="server" id="leftpane">
   <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
           // i want module 1 at here
        </td>
        <td>
           // i want module 2 at here        
        </td> 
      </tr> 
   </table>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you should set two leftpanel in the skin, like this:

```
<div id="leftpane">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                 <div runat="server" id="leftpane1"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                 <div runat="server" id="leftpane2"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```